# Neo4j Cypher Get Relationship Direction

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have following cypher query which returns all (in and out) relationships of an specific node:

```
START s=node(1) MATCH s<-[r]->(t) RETURN type(r) as RelationshipType, .......
```

Now I want to find out the direction of each relationship. Is there an command like "`RETURN RelationshipDirection(r)`" ?? :)

Thanks.

Comment: you could use something like return length(s-[r]->t) which should be 0 if it is incoming to s and 1 if it is outgoing.

Answer (score 7):

Per neo4j 2.0, you can use startnode(r)

See
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-startnode

STARTNODE returns the starting node of a relationship

So in your example you might find outgoing relations by `startnode(r) = s`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not possible right now using Cypher. [Here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/85) is an issue for it. Please add any comments you might have.

Andrés